# Custom panels-pane tpl based on some identifier

Tags: theming, panels

Is it possible to create a pane template based on some kind of identifier? Just Like you can create a page--node--123.tpl.php file to render a different page for a node with nid 123, i'd like to make a panels-pane--pid--123.tpl.php to render a specific pane with pid 123 I have tried looking on google but i have found nothing about this possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of working around & trial & error methods, I got this.

1. Copy your "**panels-pane.tpl.php**" in your current theme's template directory.
2. include dpm($pane); in a php tag. This will give u the list of all the panes on ur current panel page.
3. Note down the **pid** ($pane->pid) here.

   - If you are looking for a particular page the unqiue identifier for that whole page would be **did** ($pane->did) which is the display id.
   - Basically, every panel page has a unique **did** (display id) & different **pid** (pane Id) for all the panes on that particular page.
4. Now in your "**panels-pane.tpl.php**" in the div code block with class="pane-content" you could write a php code like

   ```
   if($pane->pid=='some id' & $pane->did=='some id') {
   //modify your pane data from the variables at $pane->configuration & store in $content.
      $content = your modified data;
      print render($content); // render this pane with my modified data
   else
   print render($content); // (and) render other panes as normal
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, that's quite a dirty solution but i get the idea. It'll do

Answer (score 0):

when you use the dpm($pane), you can also use the $pane->type variable to get the value of pane type & use this to create a separate template file that affects all the panes of this type only.

for example: In my scenario, i had added custom-content on pane. (Pane > Add content > Add custom content)
So i had a few of such content-panes, which i wanted to be wrapped around in different html divs for structuring.

In my case, on dpm($pane) this $pane->type value was "custom". (This could be view, block, etc, as per the pane data)
So I created "panels-pane--custom.tpl.php". This will affect all the panes of this (custom) type. Further, as my above answer, for a given panel node, I know my page's display id ($pane->did).

So use an if condition on this display-id & further you can use if / else-if / switch on $pane->pid for altering a particular pane.

```
    if($pane->did=='some-id') {
       switch($pane->pid) {
       case 'pid1' : some code stored into $content & then - print render($content); break;
       case 'pid2' : some code stored into $content & then - print render($content); break;
       default     : print render($content);
      }
    }
```